# How do I install Oracle Database 12c?

Tags: database, oracle

I downloaded Oracle Database 12c but I'm having trouble installing it. Can anyone help me?

Imported from the [comments below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337439/how-do-i-install-oracle-database-12c#comment430158_337457):

> Then I unzipped it and installed it, but nothing appears the installation finishes and says it was a success but nda happens. It is as if I had not installed anything. During installation appeared some messages saying that the environment does not meet all the requirements, but the installation was to the end.

Comment: Could you improve your question by providing exact error messages you see and in which step of a installation procedure you are seeing this? Please **edit** your question to include all details you can provide. We rely on all information in your question which is currently nearly nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a thorough answer you should elaborate on the problems you're experiencing.

Oracle 12c R1 has been released just recently and AFAIK there is no "tutorial" on installing Oracle 12c on Ubuntu, yet. I am afraid you have to stick with [what's in the webs for 11g R2](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/toc.htm).

The relevant prerequisites that changed from 11gR2 to 12cR1 are about [minimum required swap space](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBI/pre_install.htm#BABGCEAD) and maximum number of file descriptors (65536 instead of 4096). I did not observe any other changed pre installation requirements, but note that I actually did not install 11gR2/12cR1 on Ubuntu, but on Solaris and conclude from the differences I've observed there.

Further information:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/install.121/e17720/toc.htm

NOTE: This is an answer to the original question, if there was a tutorial for 12cR1/Ubuntu available.

Comment: Then I unzipped it and installed it, but nothing appears the installation finishes and says it was a success but nda happens. It is as if I had not installed anything. During installation appeared some messages saying that the environment does not meet all the requirements, but the installation was to the end.

Comment: Installing Oracle is not so trivial. Have a look at the links that I provided. What you did was in fact not installing, but the installation was canceled due to unmet requirements. Meeting those requirement is what all the tutorials are about. Oracle does not support Ubuntu directly.

Comment: If you desperately want to use Oracle w/o having too much trouble you may use Oracle Linux, which is supported, i.e. you can work through the primary install docs. You could also download [Oracle Developer Day Virtual Box Image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html), although that is 11gR2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see more calmly the links you passed me.

Answer (score 1):

Your are seeing "environment does not meet all the requirements" error because Ubuntu is not a certified OS to install Oracle Database. Atleast in Production Env.

I tried to install Oracle 12c Release 1 on Ubuntu 15.04 and it worked well.

Following are the steps for reference

Ensure that the /etc/hosts file must contain a fully qualified name for the server.

```
IP-address  fully-qualified-machine-name machine-name
```

Run following commands using root / root equivalent user

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot the machine

Again run dist-upgrade to check if there is any new versions of packages.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Run following command to install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -y install alien binutils build-essential \
cpp-4.4 debhelper g++-4.4 gawk gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base \
gettext html2text lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 intltool-debian \
ksh lib32z1-dev libaio-dev libaio1 libbeecrypt7 libc6 \
libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libelf-dev libelf1 libltdl-dev \
libltdl7 libmotif4 libodbcinstq4-1 libodbcinstq4-1:i386 \
libqt4-core libqt4-gui libsqlite3-0 libstdc++5 libstdc++6 \
libstdc++6-4.4-dev lsb lsb-core lsb-cxx lsb-desktop \
lsb-graphics make odbcinst pax po-debconf rpm \
rpm-common sysstat unixodbc unixodbc-dev unzip
```

Creating Required Operating System Groups and Users by running following commands

```
sudo addgroup oinstall
sudo addgroup dba
sudo addgroup nobody
sudo usermod -g nobody nobody
sudo useradd -g oinstall -G dba -p password -d /home/oracle -s /bin/bash oracle
sudo mkdir /home/oracle
sudo chown -R oracle:dba /home/oracle
sudo mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle
sudo mkdir -p /u01/binaries
sudo chown -R oracle:dba /u01
```

Set the password for the oracle user which we have created for installation purpose

```
sudo passwd oracle
```

Make ourself as Red Hat by running following command as root/ root equivalent user

```
echo 'Red Hat Linux release 6' | sudo tee -a /etc/redhat-release
```

We need to create some soft links to start the installation. To do so run the following commands as root/ root equivalent user,

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib64
sudo ln -s /etc /etc/rc.d
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib64/
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/basename /bin/basename
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/rpm /bin/rpm
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a /usr/lib64/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a /usr/lib64/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /lib64/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/
```

To change the shell configuration for oracle user run following commands as root/ root equivalent user

```
sudo cp /etc/security/limits.conf /etc/security/limits.conf.original
echo "#Oracle 12C shell limits:" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "oracle soft nproc 2048" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "oracle hard nproc 16384"| sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "oracle soft nofile 1024" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "oracle hard nofile 65536" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Run following command to change the kernel parameters as root/ root equivalent user.

```
echo "#" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "# Oracle 12C entries" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "fs.aio-max-nr=1048576" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "fs.file-max=6815744" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "kernel.shmall=2097152" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "kernel.shmmni=4096" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65500" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.core.rmem_default=262144" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.core.rmem_max=4194304" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.core.wmem_default=262144" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.core.wmem_max=1048586" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "kernel.shmmax=1073741824" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Note: kernel.shmmax = max possible value, e.g. size of physical memory in bytes. In my case machine is having 2GB so we are specifying 1GB. Adjust the parameter as per your configuration

Load new kernel parameters, by running following as root/ root equivalent user.

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

We need to do changes in start-up script, run following commands as root/ root equivalent user

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 S
do sudo ln -s /etc/rc$i.d /etc/rc.d/rc$i.d
done
```

I have downloaded the binaries in /u01/binaries folder.
To extract the binaries run following commands

```
cd /u01/binaries
unzip linuxamd64_12102_database_1of2.zip
unzip linuxamd64_12102_database_2of2.zip
```

Before doing the installation we need to give proper permission to the extracted file, to do the same run following command

```
chown -Rf oracle:dba /u01/binaries
```

Login as a oracle user and start installation using following command

```
cd /u01/binaries/database
/u01/binaries/database/runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs
```

And complete the set up there after.
Remember Ubuntu is not certifies OS for Oracle Database. In case of any issues follow below post.
[How to Install Oracle 12c on Ubuntu 15.04](http://www.techienote.com/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit I managed to succeed with the Oracle 12c software setup:

1. My system used to be Ubuntu 12.04 with Oracle 11.2, later upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04. So I think I already had the relevant packages and symlinks in `/usr/lib64`.
   If you're starting from scratch: just follow all apt-get and `ln -s` instructions from http://wp.me/p1o1k2-6J (do this before starting the setup)
2. For __tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3 errors I followed following instructions (written for Fedora but worked on Ubuntu too): http://gumpx.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/install-oracle-11-2-x-to-12-1-0-1-on-fedora-17-19/
   I.e.

   - `rm -rf ${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/stubs`
   - Edit `${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/lib/env_rdbms.mk`

     - Add `-lons` to `LINKTTLIBS`
     - Add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to `LINK` and `LINK32`
     - Add `-lnnz12` to `TG4PWD_LINKLINE`
3. The rest of the issues have been solved by the above-mentioned in step (1) article provided by @gemsofprogramming
   I don't recall all linking errors which I faced but for all of them I managed to search and find a fix in the mentioned article.
   E.g. - on kfed link failure: edit `env_rdbms.mk` by adding `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to `KFED_LINKLINE`.

Comment: An *answer* without content is only useless text. Take a time and explain what methods to use *here*.